# How to add variables to a template

Tags: templates, query, include, template-include

I am using a query argument `detail` to check if a custom template should be loaded. This works fine, but I also need to add some variables that can be accessed from within the template. Here I am using `add_action('template_include' array($this, 'templateInclude')`:

```
public function templateInclude($template)
{
    if (get_query_var('detail', false) !== false) {
        // Check theme directory first.
        $newTemplate = locate_template(array('detail.php'));
        if ($newTemplate != '')
            return $newTemplate;

        // Check plugin directory next.
        $newTemplate = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/detail.php';
        if (file_exists($newTemplate)) {
            return $newTemplate;
        }
    }

    // Return default template.
    return $template;
}
```

The above works, but of course I am not able to actually set any variables for the template.

I tried using `set_query_var()` to set a variable that could be accessed using `get_query_var()`, but this does not really seem to be the best solution.

I also tried using `add_action('template_redirect' array($this, 'templateRedirect')`, which works but this neither seems to be a really good solution:

```
public function templateRedirect() {
    if (get_query_var('detail')) {
        $detailId = get_query_var('detail', null);
        // Set a variable 'data' that can be used inside the template
        $data = get_detail($detailId);
        include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/detail.php';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Would be really great if someone has some nice way of adding custom variables for a specific template.

Comment: Sounds like you need global variables that are access from multiple places. I would instantiate a singleton class with static functions to get and set variables.

Comment: I only need to access the variable inside the template file. So the question is how to pass a variable to the actual template. If I included the file using a normal `require_once` then I could achieve this by doing `$data = get_detail($detailId); require_once 'template.php';`

Comment: Jeffrey von Grumbkow's answer still applies. There are multiple places (1) the plugin setting the variables, and (2) your template file. https://carlalexander.ca/singletons-in-wordpress/

Comment: @the_hobbes - use a singleton to setup global variables does not seem to be the best way of achieving this, especially since the variables just needs to be available and accessed in the custom template?

Comment: :shrug: You have two places that need access to something. Either reduce that (i.e. let your template file figure out how to get the data itself) or give them a shared resource. FWIW a singleton is not creating global variables per se. It's a shared resource class that both places can get to.

Comment: @the_hobbes I now what a singleton is =) Just feels like it should not be needed in this case, the only thing I would like to do is to simply add a variable to the context of a custom template.

Comment: Yeah. Well like I said you could let your template file retrieve it directly instead of sharing a variable.

Comment: Since the template gets included using some function like `include` or `require` I was more looking for a way to simply pass variables to the custom template e.g `wp_include_template('custom-template.php', array('detail' => $detail));` or something similar.

Comment: [This is how WordPress handles it’s own data](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_template/). Whatever you come up with can’t possibly be worse.